# How does Acumatica calculate LastDateTimeModified

Tags: acumatica

I have recently noticed that retrieving the LastDateTimeModified (through the WebService API) from Acumatica gives me the date and time in a very different time zone - I am guessing GMT time.

However when I view this through a Generic Inquiry it seems that it is showing the correct time - based on my Time Zone set up in the user profile.

Is there a way to get the LastDateTimeModified in the correct time zone when retrieving from the Web Service API. I have attempted changing the Time Zone for the SDK user with no success

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 2):

For most screens, except a few CRM screens, the LastDateTimeModified and CreatedDateTime are stored in the same time zone as the database server machine. When reading it using web services, you are retrieving the raw value form the database, with no timezone conversion. It is up to you to convert it to the desired timezone.

The Help->Audit History panel does a manual conversion to the current user time zone. I have not been able to get the generic inquiry to show the time as you mention in your question; it is only showing the date.