# Acumatica: Change Timezone for Last Modified field on Sales Order

Tags: acumatica

I added the available LastModifiedDateTime field to the Sales Order screen, but it is showing up in UTC (that is the timezone that the AWS server is on).

What is the best way to convert this to our local timezone? I assume it would be best to simply convert the field but i am not sure the best way to do this. Any ideas?

I did see Gabriel's response to [How does Acumatica calculate LastDateTimeModified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707073/how-does-acumatica-calculate-lastdatetimemodified/36797214#36797214) but he doesn't actually say *how* to change the timezone of that field.

Comment: I do not recommend changing the values of audit fields.  For each user, you can set the timezone.  Check out the user profile screen, and set the proper timezone.  If you can add the audit field to your form/grid, check and see if the values display in the timezone which is specific to the user.  Login as the user, and see if the timezone values change.

Comment: The change is actually occurring upon save. At first, before the line is committed, it displays the correct timezone (user profile timezone). then when it is committed it changes the timezone to UTC...